# Word order after the word "or"

Tags: word-order

Does "or" change the word order back to normal in case of a question?
Is sentence A or B correct?

A)Take me as your addiction ...
or can't you become dependent on me?

B)Take me as your addiction ...
or you can't become dependent on me?

Thanks

Comment: In the first one, "can't you" is the word order for a question.  Because of ? at the end, I am assuming that is what you mean.

Comment: If you left out 'or' both sentences would be ok. The firs uses the common word order for questioning; the second is a statement which can be made into a question with the right intonation.

Answer (score 2):

Both A and B are correct but they have different meanings.
A) Take me as your addiction ...or **are you unable to** become dependent on me?
B) Take me as your addiction ... or **you will be unable to** become dependent on me.
A) Is questioning *(can't you)* their ability to become dependent.
B) Is not a question, it is a statement *(you can't)* that you will be unable to become dependent unless you take me as your addiction.